# Regex to match a phone number ignoring non digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to match a phone number in regex when there is a non standard format in the data.  How would you write a regex to match 0408111 in all 4 of these examples?

```
(04) 0811 111
0408-111111
0408111111
0a4b0c8d1e1f1g
```

The best I came up with is:

```
/0[^\d]*4[^\d]*0[^\d]*8[^\d]*1[^\d]*1[^\d]*1/g
```

But is there a better way?

```js
var haystack = `
(04) 0811 111
0408-111111
0408111111
0a4b0c8d1e1f1g
`;
var needle = /0[^\d]*4[^\d]*0[^\d]*8[^\d]*1[^\d]*1[^\d]*1/g;
var result = haystack.match(needle);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will help, read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex/63771966#63771966

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted.. it was to search a field in a database for a particular number but it only accepts regex. I'm not using it to see if it is a valid number.

Comment: Are you trying to match a string to a particular number? Or you have some more general rules?

Comment: Yes it is trying to find a particular number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example string from your question.

```js
let haystack = `
(04) 0811 111
0408-111111
0408111111
0a4b0c8d1e1f1g
`
```

One solution to return the string `'0408111'` each time digits appear in this order within each line of `haystack` whilst discounting any non-numerical interspersed within each line would be to:

1. Remove any non-numerical characters from `haystack`
2. Return all matches of the pattern `/0408111/g`

```js
let result = haystack.replace(/[^\d\n]/g, '').match(/0408111/g)
```

Given `haystack` as above, `result` will be `[ '0408111', '0408111', '0408111', '0408111' ]`.

Since you say that you are using this to search for phone numbers within each line of the input string and the example you gave in your question is seeking a match on 7 consecutive digits in each line regardless of any non-numeric characters. The above code could be adjusted as to match the first 7 digits in each line once non-numeric characters have been removed - by matching on `/\d{7}/g` instead `/0408111/g` pattern.

e.g

```js
let haystack = `
(04) 0811 111
0454-14717181
0768551351111
0tY4lopj9pjo5567
0a4b0c8d1e1f1g
123456
`

let result = haystack.replace(/[^\d\n]/g, '').match(/\d{7}/g)
```

Here `result` will be `[ '0408111', '0454147', '0768551', '0495567', '0408111' ]`